# Looking for a cable/connector design with twisted pairs and power

Tags: connector, cables, wire

I have project where I will be running multiple peripheral devices at different voltages, and having them all communicate through differential I2C. I'm looking to find a cable that has at least 2 twisted pairs(3 would be ideal), and power/GND wires that can handle up to 5A @60V. I'd also be curious to know about what board-harness connectors are available for given cabling as well. Something like PTZ cable seems close to what I'm looking for, but I haven't found good board connectors for the higher power as I don't believe standard DB9 would be able to carry that power level. Cables will all be under ~3ft in length. Like more like 1-2ft for most of them.

Comment: Hello.  Can I ask how long the cables are?

Comment: Yes good question, i updated the post with some lengths, all under 3 feet likely 1-2ft.

Comment: `I don't believe standard DB9 would be able to carry that power level.` Most of D connectors are rated for 5A per pin. But you can use multiple pins for power, of course.

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea, I had thought about that as an option, I was just wondering if there were any other standard options out there.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the title haha @jsotola

Comment: Have you considered the Molex 39-01-2040 Minifit jr type, used for P4 power supplies and similar.  I use them for power + 1 pair RS-485.  5A up to 12.5A depending on various configuratinos, available with whatever number of pins you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are many hybrid wire-to-board connectors. My [Select-a-conn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=S&a=------&c=Iw-----H----) suggests these:

- [Partitioned shroud connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=partitioned_shroud_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000-600-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C), Amphenol FCI 10129815-44400LF (Mini-Fit-like, but hybrid)
- [Screw latch connector](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=screw_latch_rect_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000-600-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C), Harwin Datamate Mix-Tek and Gecko MT
- [Unsealed automotive connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=unsealed_automotive_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000-600-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C), Molex Stac64
- [Sealed automotive connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=sealed_automotive_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000-600-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C), Molex MX 150
- [D-Sub hybrid](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=d_sub_conn&s=DB-13W3): industy-standard [13W3](https://www.digikey.se/short/4jp7j955)

---

Consider also doubling-up circuits in a standard (non-hybrid) connector so that 2 or 3 contacts share the high current.